# Add an operation to pipe conditionally with RXJS

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I need to make a API call before another API call conditionally. The scenario is that I have a form along with two buttons, save and finalize. When I press finalize, the form value needs to be saved first if it has been changed. This is my current solution, but it's not really how I want to do this (I don't want an array as the result, I only want the last one):

```
const operations$ = [];

if (form.dirty) {
  operations$.push(myService.saveTheThing(form.value).pipe(...))
}

operations$.push(myService.finalizeTheThing().pipe(...));

combineLatest(operations$).subscribe(() -> { ... });
```

I don't really care about the save operation result in the subscribe block, I'd rather just receive the one value returned by `finalizeTheThing()` instead of an array that the `combineLatest` returns. Here's another thing I tried which resembles what I want, but obviously it doesn't work this way:

```
const stream$ = of(null);

if (form.dirty) {
  stream$.pipe(
    switchMap(() => myService.saveTheThing(form.value).pipe(...))
  );
}

stream$.pipe(
  switchMap(() => myService.finalizeTheThing()
);

stream$.subscribe(myThing => { ... })
```

And of course if `saveTheThing()` fails, `finalizeTheThing()` should not be called. What would be the proper pattern for this kind of scenario?

Comment: [concat](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concat.html) and [concatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html) may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems `switchMap(_ => condition ? doAnotherCall() : of(SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE))` would work just fine. In short, you `swtichMap` to an "do-nothing" `Observable` depending upon condition of the same type as "do-something" would be. That's a common practice in functional programming.

Other - much more functional and yet much harder to get right for newcommers - is `higher order observable`: you could have an `Observable` that itself produce `Observable` based on some parametrization - in your case, based on condition you've mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

you can condense the code like below

```
of(form.dirty).pipe(
   switchMap(dirty=>dirty?myService.saveTheThing(form.value):of(true)),
   switchMap(e=>myService.finalizeTheThing())
)
```